# Android contextual action bar title styling

Tags: android

I am using androids "text selection" contextual actionbar, as far I have managed to change the icons to my custom coloured and the divider, however I am unable to change the colour of the text "Text selection" Currently it is black/dark and I want it to be green.. I have been looking and trying different things but nothing seems to work, any idea what might resolve my problem?